# We are having issues with accessing our websites on multiple Wifi's, but 4g works always. Wordpress hosted on digital ocean

Tags: wordpress, server, hosting, digital-ocean

Both us, and our clients are having issues, while trying to access the development servers on digital ocean. Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes we get errors and are unable to access the website. However, then we switch over to 4g network, and can access the website without a hassle.

Could this be some kind of a automatic IP blocking on Digital ocean's side?

Here is an example of an website on our server

https://nyjasaf.bigsheepstudios.com

********* New Information *********

Ran this command on the server `iptables -L INPUT -v -n`

Got this info:
[Screen shot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8VMQ.png)

But would it make sense that it would be IP blocking, since it only happens sometimes?

Comment: "Could this be some kind of a automatic IP blocking on Digital ocean's side?" - why not to check that? Login to SSH and make sure Server Firewall hasn't blocked some IP addresses.  (Google: how to list blocked address using iptables)

Comment: What errors do you get? are you running iptables or the cloud firewall?